# Google Analytics Tracking Code in .js File

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm new to web development and am undertaking a pretty simple project that I am having problems with.  I'm using Google analytics for my site.  I want the tracker code in all of my pages.  So, I'm using Javascript, which is loaded in every page's head.

The first thing I did was use jQuery's append() to insert the code, which is provided by Google enclosed in script tags, at the end of the head tag.  I had to escape out newlines and replace single quotes with double to use it in a string being passed to append().  While I can see from console log messages I've created that the code runs, Google analytics says the tracker is not installed.

Next I thought that the above was a bit too complicated.  Since the tracker is asynchronous I figured I could just paste it into a .js file (minus the script tags that wrap it, obviously).  This similarly seems to work as console log messages appear and I can see mysterious style tags appear in Chrome's element inspector.  But Google Analytics still says the tracker is not installed.

I've done quite a bit of searching on this subject and found articles that say that putting the Javascript part of the tracker in an external JS file "should work but is not recommended".  I'm not sure how exactly I should interpret that.  I've even installed Chrome's Google Analytics debugging plugin, which produces all kinds of information about my site in the console, which suggests things are working.  Yet the analytics page continues to say "Tracking Not Installed".

Can anyone give a newbie a recommendation?  What is the preferred way to insert GA tracker code from Javascript?  Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

**edit**: After even more searching I may be onto something.  GA real time is showing some activity.  So, something must be working.  But the admin's panel says Status: "Tracking Not Installed Last checked: May 23, 2014 12:00:48 AM PDT", which is just one minute ago.  I think that message is incorrect.  Maybe Google's status checker is not really checking that frequently.

**last edit**: I've confirmed that what I saw was a bug in the Google Analytics UI.  I've reported the bug to Google.  We'll see if they act.  But, in short, the Google tracker status is only updated every 2-3 days.  The "Last checked" date is a lie.  The right way to instantly check if tracker code is working is to look at the Real-time stats.

Comment: Maybe google Analytics checks if it's installed on a client with javascript disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put Google Analytics script in your header? i don't think that jquery.append will work because,when it do it browser will not execute that script that you append that way,if you want to include analytics from a js,so use requirejs or something like that http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

Have a footer in your webpages

Paste the google analytics script in Footer instead of header as some of the search engine crawler read first few KB of your web page. This is technic is followed by plenty of websites including StackOverflow.

Placing the google analytics code by javascript append is not a good practice.